# 5.1 Audio Unavailable in VLC

Tags: 11.10, vlc

Running VLC on Ubuntu 11.10, I am not able to use 5.1 ch output.

In Windows, Whwn I right click, and then choose **Audio** on the contextual menu, I can set the device to 5.1 ch....

However, in my Ubuntu setup, only the Audio Track selection is active, the Audio channel and Audio Device option are grayed out....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You must audio systems settings,

[image]

Choose the hardware tab, on the hardware tab select your device and next select stereo digital output

[image]

Select the correct profile for your speakers.

I got 5.1 with that and I use an external AV Amplifier.